# How to check multidimension array key and value same or not?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is my two different array.
First and multiple key and value and Second array every time change.
How to check array key and value same or not?

```
$array1 = array(
        '5' => array(
            'survey' => array('survey_list', 'add')
        )
    );
    $array2 = array(
        $id => array(
            $key => array($value)
        )
    );
```

Output

```
Array
(
[5] => Array
    (
        [survey] => Array
            (
                [0] => survey_list
                [1] => add
            )

    )

)

Array
(
[5] => Array
    (
        [survey] => Array
            (
                [0] => survey_list
            )

    )

)
```

I have tried array_intersect() but that does not work because this is a multidimensional array.

Comment: Your input and output is the same. They are just formatted differently

Comment: @Andreas is right. May be this documentation could help you to understand array : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php (see Example #2)